# How to align contents in the middle in div class row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i was wondering if anyone can assist in what it should have been a straight forward issue to fix when it comes to aligning the text ("CONSOL Overview") in the middle instead of left in the title box below.

I have tried "align-content: center" and also "text-align: center" but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any help apprecieated

my html page looks like this: 
[image]

and the part in the html code is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="row" 
         style="height: 50px;padding-top: 15px; background: #36304a; align-content: center; color: white; font-weight: bold; border-radius: 10px">
        <h3>CONSOL Overview</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Actually there more elements  below my title but i guess those aren't needed to be shown here.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 or newer, then the `row` class is `display: flex` by default, which means `<div class="row justify-content-center">` should place every item in your div horizontally center. If you want to it horizontally and vertically center then use `<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">`

The other way is, if your containers height is set, then simply make your text's line-height equal with it and it will be in center. (works only if the text is only in one row)

Comment: thanks I will test it, i am using <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: <div class="row justify-content-center"> makes it horizontally center

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using Bootstrap and there is a really easy way to align elements in the center using    `mx-auto` like    `<div class="mx-auto">` or    `<h3 class="mx-auto">`. :)

Comment: thanks I will test it, i am using <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes catch up with the results! This link does not seem to work!

Comment: There's no need for that. If he wants the h3 to be vertically centered, then a simple text-align: center; would be enough on the div. mx-auto is not needed on any of the classes. If he is using bootstrap then there is the "text-center" class which will place the text vertically center. The row's align-items-center class will place it horizontally centered.

Comment: I agree @PatrikAlexits, but since bootstrap gives us a simple class for that why go to css for that buddy?

Comment: There is no need for css, that's why I wrote the "text-center" class on the div. That will place the <h3> vertically center since it's a text within a div. The "align-item-center" will place it horizontally centered within a div.

Comment: Yes I guess there is no need for this man! Both the answers do the work! @SNicolaou may use the way they prefer!

Comment: so far I have tested <h3 class="mx-auto">CONSOL Overview</h3>  and it works

Comment: and <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center"> also works so thank you both.

Comment: Welcome! @SNicolaou ! Glad it works! Please accept the answer if you are satisfied!

Comment: Okay I see it now, I haven't noticed that you wrote "center instead of left side". My bad sorry :)

Comment: Adding ```mx-auto``` to the class worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is solution to your problem

```
    h3{
display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LSKhan/qyb051px/1/)